# Issues with including Objective-C class in my xcode project

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, subclass

I am relatively new to Objective-C, about 1 year experience, and I had encountered an issue with trying to add a class to my project. When I add a class of UIViewController subclass, with XIB file included, I have no problems with that at all, xcode is working very well that way.

However, I tried to add a simple Objective-C class to the project called Test, with the following .h and .m files, and had a problem where the code compiles and builds without error but the method TestMethod always returns nil. What might be wrong here?

Test.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Test;

@interface Test : NSObject {

}

- (NSString *)TestMethod;

@end
```

Test.m

```
#import "Test.h"

@implementation Test

- (NSString*)TestMethod {
    return @"Test";
}

@end
```

In my `UIViewController` subclass with XIB file, that subclass works without error, but when I try to include my Test class in it, the method TestMethod returns nothing, even though it is hardcoded to always return the same string:

```
#import "Test.h"

Test *testobject;

// this compiles and builds but returns nothing
NSString *testString = [testobject TestMethod];
```

Answer (score 3):

You missed to alloc + init.

Use

```
Test *testobject=[[Test alloc] init];
```

or

```
Test *testobject=[Test new];
```

**Whenever your object is un-initialised you will get `nil` value.**

EDIT:

In **ARC** : it's default initialized .

In **MRC** : the value could be uninitialized (garbage value).

Comment: none of the answers make the distinction: *Whenever your object is un-initialised you will get nil value.* -- it's default initialized in ARC. in MRC, the value could be uninitialized (garbage value).

Comment: @justin: so what more should be there in the answer?

Comment: @justin - In MRC, this would only happen if an object was created and then released.  This is not the case in the author`s post.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya i don't know if you want to spell out that distinction in your answer. plus, i've already upvoted it. i was just saying that under ARC `Test *testobject;` **will** be `nil`, and that `Test *testobject;` under MRC may be `nil` or it may be a garbage value. the statement i quoted is not correct under MRC (because the runtime could read an invalid pointer), but every answerer must have made the assumption that it was ARC. so i am just supplementing the answer -- you can change it if you like but i don't think it is necessary to change.

Comment: @justin: sure... i will go with the change you mentioned.

Comment: @AaronBrager nope. `Test * testobject; \n NSString *testString = [testobject TestMethod];` will trigger a `-Wuninitialized` warning, and clang will suggest you initialize the variable (again, in MRC). go ahead and try it.

Comment: @AaronBrager also, the category of error you have described would not be an uninitialized value, but a use after release.

Comment: @justin You're right, because it's a local, nonstatic variable.  (I was remembering the behavior of instance variables in MRC.)

Comment: Thanks Anoop that is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for replying to my post you saved me quite a bit of work

Answer (score 1):

TestMethod isn't returing `nil` - `testobject` is nil.

Change

`Test *testobject;`

to

`Test *testobject = [[Test alloc] init];`

Answer (score 1):

You have not created an instance of Test, so testObject just holds nil. You need to assign an instance of Test to the variable in order to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take this approach

```
//Test.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Test;

@interface Test : NSObject {
}
- (id)init;
-(NSString*)TestMethod;

@end
```

Now in your Test.m file

//Test.m

```
#import "Test.h"

@implementation Test


- (id)init {

     if (self=[super init]) {

     }
     return self;
}

-(NSString*)TestMethod {
return @"Test";
}

@end
```

Now if you want to call this Test Class in another class, you have to create an instance of Test Class.

```
Test *testobject = [[Test alloc] init];

NSString *testString = [testobject TestMethod];
```

Answer (score 0):

To access any method/property of a class, first you need to allocate memory to object of that class using alloc/new method.

Since you created variable of that class type `<Test *testobject>`. But variable does not allocated any memory, by default it will be nil. Using "nil" you can call any method in objective C. It will not crash. But it will return nil.

So, Before accessing any object you must created memory for that object

```
Test *testobject = [Test alloc];
```

initialized the object with default constructor (init, initWith, etc...)

```
[testobject init];
```

Now object is ready for calling  instance method/setter/getter etc...

```
NSString *testString = [testobject TestMethod];
```